# solar panel voltage 50mV to 1V

Tags: voltage, amplifier, voltage-regulator

I am getting about 50mV from a small solarpanel.  What can I do so that I can increase it and get about 1V?  I need it to power an led.  It does no have to have any external battery source to amplify the voltage.

Comment: Not much if you still expect to be able to use _any_ power what so ever from it..

Comment: A typical solar cell should have a 0.5V nominal. I think you have a bad cell / array.

Comment: Measure the short circuit current under that condition, do a rough calculation of the maximum power and see if it is enough for anything (I have my doubts). Then look into specialized energy harvesting Step-Up-Converters which operate on very low voltages.

Comment: What is your light source? What is your load for this test? Tell us: Unloaded voltage in full sun. Short circuit current in full sun.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I go 50mV with the multimeter when it has no load on it

Comment: @suyol854 Partial answers to 4 questions is of about no use, alas. Please answer all 4 questions above if possible. You MUST know light source,

Comment: If you want useful answers you MUST give more details. What light source? is a key factor. Specific knowledge about the panel is also required. How many separate cells? Does it have a known rating? What are you wanting to power with it?

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting about 50mV from a small solarpanel. What can I do so that I can increase it and get about 1V?

Expose it to more light.

The full voltage of a solar panel is usually specified under full sunlight.  Indoor light is *much* less, despite what your eyes may tell you.

Comment: This is the right answer, but I have a feeling it is not what OP wanted to hear...

Comment: @Pipe: Yeah, physics can be inconvenient like that.

Comment: I mean to amplify it without exposing it to more light

Comment: @suyol854, then put that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A PV panel Vmp must be about 80% of Voc regardless of solar input+/- 5% depending on load.

Therefore your load current is too high for size of PV.

You can try to reduce current to regulate Max Power at Vmp or use a bigger PV.

Comment: Tony - he is doing something "non standard and so far has not answered questions aimed at finding out what he is doing. He says " ... RussellMcMahon I go 50mV with the multimeter when it has no load on it." -> which suggests low light, or dead panel or maybe a 50 year old Selenium cell or ... .

Comment: yes or measure short circuit current and voltage at same time.

Answer (score -2):

This circuit should convert your 50 mV to 1 V. The OP-amp must be able to handle inputs near its negative rail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSqSRT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way you can do it without using an external battery source.

Comment: @suyol854 Not really.

Comment: The question demands that there should not be use of any external voltage sources.

Comment: @SoumyaSambeetMohapatra Yes, as you can see, that impossible requirement was added after my answer. His question is now "I want more power without changing anything and without shining more light".